# Как преобразовать рекурсию в функцию в plpgsql?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, рекурсия, plpgsql

у меня есть этот рабочий код, но мне нужно преобразовать его в функцию с динамическим атрибутом `tid = 1645`, где число 1645 всегда будет меняться.

```
with recursive r as (
    select tid, boss from titles where tid=1645
    union
    select titles.tid, titles.boss from titles join r on titles.tid = r.boss
)
select * from r
```

Сейчас есть это:

```
DROP FUNCTION bosses_of_rsd_tids(integer);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.bosses_of_rsd_tids(rsd_tid int)
    RETURNS table (c_tid int, c_boss int)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    begin
        with recursive r as (
            select tid, boss from titles where tid=rsd_tid
            union
            select titles.tid, titles.boss from titles join r on titles.boss = r.tid
        )

        select c_tid, c_boss;
    end;
 $function$
;
```

В результате мне нужна таблица результатов ... Я пытался `return select c_tid, c_boss;` но была ошибка: около return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.bosses_of_rsd_tids(rsd_tid int)
  RETURNS TABLE (c_tid int, c_boss int) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
      SELECT tid, boss
      FROM   titles
      WHERE  tid = rsd_tid

      UNION ALL                           -- ?!
      SELECT t.tid, t.boss
      FROM   r
      JOIN   titles t ON t.tid = r.boss   -- !
      )
   TABLE r;                               -- !
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

`TABLE r` сокращение от SELECT * FROM r. А моя запись `select c_tid, c_boss` была ошибочной.

[How convert recursive to function in plpgsql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56024395/how-convert-recursive-to-function-in-plpgsql)

Answer (score 0):

В смысле вы хотите просто спрятать запрос в хранимку? А зачем вам тогда plpgsql для этого? Простого `language sql` достаточно:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.bosses_of_rsd_tids(int)
    RETURNS table (c_tid int, c_boss int)
    LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
        with recursive r as (
            select tid, boss from titles where tid=$1
            union
            select titles.tid, titles.boss from titles join r on titles.boss = r.tid
        )
        select c_tid, c_boss from r;
 $function$;
```

Ну а для plpgsql есть специальная конструкция [`return query`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.bosses_of_rsd_tids(rsd_tid int)
    RETURNS table (c_tid int, c_boss int)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    begin
        return query with recursive r as (
            select tid, boss from titles where tid=rsd_tid
            union
            select titles.tid, titles.boss from titles join r on titles.boss = r.tid
        )
        select c_tid, c_boss from r;
    end;
 $function$;
```

Просто `return` - это для формирования результата, но не для возврата набора строк. Например, для `returns bool` функций.

Comment: Во втором случае (сработало) странный результат выдается. Если без функции применять, то значения `1645 15169; 15169 1731; 1731 13602; 13602 NULL`, а если первый, то огромное количество записей. Без функции - верно

Comment: я очень косо смотрю на union. Сильно похоже на ошибку вместо того, что так и было задумано. Точно union? Не union all? (нет желания осмысливать особенности поведения union в рекурсивном запросе) Ну и ваши значения без воспроизводимого примера таблицы (с примером данных) в вопросе мне не говорят ровным счётом ничего.

Comment: попробовал union all - то же самое